# Ignore a CSS rule from a stylesheet

Tags: css, telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik Reporting with an MVC 3 site.  I followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.telerik.com/careypayette/posts/13-03-26/telerik-reporting-in-mvc-sure-it-takes-8-quick-steps-) to set up my report viewer page and have the CSS conflict issue mentioned at the end of the tutorial.  They recommend just *removing the rules* from `Site.css` so their styles will apply properly.

I don't really like that solution.  I want to be free to use the `Site.css` styles on all my non Telerik report pages and still have Telerik work properly.  Is there a way (css or javascript) to remove the offending rules from my stylesheet on the report page only?

Comment: What types of rules are you trying to ignore? are they rules on specific elements or classes? there are ways to remove classes from elements so you may not need to remove the CSS rule. On the other hand, if we are talking about CSS rules on specific elements, you might have to change the CSS to the default or make a new class to override the old CSS rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a class on the body of your report page

```
<body class="report">
```

And then in your style sheet:

```
.report .someelement {
     // The styles that fix the problem, e.g.
     position: static;

}
```